# gulp 4.0.0 shows npm outdated

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I am running the latest available Gulp.js 4.0.0 and yet somehow npm says this:

```
> npm outdated
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
gulp       4.0.0   4.0.0   3.9.1
```

To solve the issue I have done:

- `npm update`
- `npm update -g`
- remove node_modules and run `npm install` [lependu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247818/5153030)
- remove node_modules, `npm cache clean -f` and run `npm install` [lependu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247818/5153030)

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

npm had some issues with publication of new packages this week and the week before too. See [this](https://twitter.com/npmstatus/status/1060323878591881217) So I guess an `npm cache clean -f` would help. If not, you can do nothing more, than wait.

Comment: Cleaning npm cache did not solve the problem. I have been facing this issue for a couple of weeks now so I am not sure if it really has something to do with the link you have mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, the first incedent report is from november 2. Do you reinstall node_modules too? Or maybe if gulp installed as global, you need to reinstall the global packages too.

Comment: So you basically put together my comments and selling as your own. Nice play.

Comment: You have misunderstood me and I appreciate your input. I have tried what you have suggested. Your suggestion did not work. I have mentioned your suggestion in the steps that did to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please, think a bit: What is the point to clear npm cache if you leave the already installed modules in place? Also you stated in your first comment that it is not working. Then when I explained to you what steps you missed and after that you update your own message with the steps I told you to do.